# Open, save and edit embedded excel sheet inside application

Tags: c#, excel, embed, ole

I've managed to embed an excel sheet onto my windows form application with the help of these two examples:
[Example 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/304662/how-to-use-the-webbrowser-control-to-open-office-documents-in-visual-c) and [Example 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati).

The examples are copied pretty much straight off. 
However, I have yet to understand how I can manipulate the excel application/window through code. What I mean by that is I need to be able to:

- Show/Hide excel toolbar (Function in Example 1 doesn't work for me.)
- Protect sheets
- Save range of cells as .csv (alt. run excel macro)
- Change between displaying different excel files.

Things that also would be nice:

- When loading up an excel sheet, to not having an open/save dialog window show up every time.
- A good way of disposing of excel workbooks when loadin up a new one to avoid the error "Can't open an excel file when an excel file of the same name is already open."

My ideas so far. 
I'm pretty sure that in some way I need to attach the active worksheet/workbook to a global variabel that has the properties needed for my needs. However, thus far when I have tried something like that I usually get a reference missing error or something similar, even though I think i'm doing the right thing.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this.excelWrapper1.GetActiveWorkbook(FileName).Protect();
        //wb.Protect();
        //this.excelWrapper1.m_Workbook.Protect();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        app.ThisWorkbook.Protect(); // Doesn't work
    }
```

With this code I get this:

```
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in EmbeddedExcel.exe
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Thank you in advance!

Note: I can't use payware to do what I need. Free is fine.

Comment: Did you try debugging ?

Comment: @Rafalon Yes. However, I am not familiar with this type of program which makes it difficult to find the correct way of fixing the error.